# Age Calculator in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have following sQL query, which is showing correct result as "28 Year, 1 Month, 16 Day old".

But, I want, it shows display as in years,months,days (in plural) if their number is more than 1.

For example- In above result, year is greater than 1, then it shows 28 Years.

```
Declare @DOB datetime,@TempDate datetime,@Year int,@Month int,@Day int
Set @DOB='09/13/1991'
Set @TempDate=@DOB

Select @Year=DateDiff(Year,@TempDate,getdate())-
                Case
                When (Month(@TempDate)>Month(getdate()) or Month(@TempDate)=Month(getdate()) AND Day(@TempDate)>Day(getdate()))
                Then 1
                Else 0
                End

Select @TempDate=DateAdd(YEAR,@Year,@DOB)
Select @Month=DateDiff(Month,@TempDate,getdate())-
                Case
                When (Month(@TempDate)>Month(getdate()) OR Day(@TempDate)>Day(getdate()))
                Then 1
                Else 0
                End

Select @TempDate=DateAdd(Month,@Month,@TempDate)

Select @Day=DateDiff(Day,@TempDate,getdate())

Select Cast(@Year as nvarchar(2))+ ' Year, '+Cast(@Month as nvarchar(2))+ ' Month, '+Cast(@Day as nvarchar(2))+' Day old'
```

Comment: If you want `'Years'` or `'Year'`, that should really be something for the presentation layer. Pass a column for the value of Years, Months, days, (etc?) and then have the application do the formatting.

Comment: Off topic: `Cast(@Year as nvarchar(2))` <- what about people over 99 years old?

Comment: @Larnu I'd say that people wanting to learn how to apply logic in SQL should not be discouraged from doing so. It might be a school assignment, in that case telling them that the assignment is wrong is of no help.

Comment: If it's a school assignment, @PeterB, the OP should be doing the work themselves, not us. ;) I'm not discouraging them wanting to learn, I'm discouraging them from doing it in SQL. Presentation layers exist for a reason. :)

Comment: this is a good question, because it shows the existing efforts of the questioner.

Comment: Thanks everyone here..for stooping here to see this question, and posting your individual feedback. I really appreciate this, and thanks from bottom of my heart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example try this:

```
SELECT CAST(@Year AS NVARCHAR(2)) + IIF(@Year > 1,' Years, ','Year, ') + CAST(@Month AS NVARCHAR(2)) + IIF(@Month > 1,' Months, ',' Month, ') + CAST(@Day AS NVARCHAR(2)) + IIF(@Day > 1,' Days ',' Day ') + 'old'
```

Comment: Thanks a lots...god bless you

Comment: You're welcome! please accept my answer if you are satisfied with it ;-)

Comment: I'm glad you found a useful answer. Please consider accepting the answer by clicking on the grey check mark to the left. It rewards the person who answered with some reputation points, and you get some, too.